# Delete everything inside body and after class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to delete script inside body and after div with class footer.

Code:

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="wrap"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"></script> <-- should be removed
</body>
```

Comment: You want to put it after footer class div?

Comment: @Yogesh Sharma Hi, no I need to removed that script tag

Comment: What is the behaviour you are expecting by removing script element? And btw as `.footer` is part of body, your satement `I have to delete script inside body and after div with class footer` doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
$('.footer + script').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative you could use this:

```
$(".footer").next("script").remove();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6YGp3/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Using
`$(".footer + script").remove();` will do the trick.